# Git - how to remove branch from checkout autocomplete

Tags: linux, git, terminal

I've deleted some local branches via `git branch -d branchname`, but they are still exist in autocomplete (when I put `git checkout`, then press `tab` key, I see all deleted branches in list).

I've tried to make `git gc` and `git prune`, but nothing changes.

Comment: Have you tried commiting and pushing your changes?

you can try `git branch -D the_local_branch`. But be careful. This will delete the branch even if it not merged.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are *sure* that you do not want the branch, you can remove it from your local *and* the remote like this:

```
$ git branch -D branchname
$ git push origin :branchname
```

Then it will stop appearing in autocomplete results.

Comment: I've pushed changes to the `origin/branchname`, then the changes were merged with `origin/master` and `origin/branchname` were deleted on the remote. I still see both `branchname` and `origin/branchname` in the autocomplete. `origin/branchname` is ok, I want to delete only local, because there is too many deleted branches.

Comment: If you want to delete the local then run only the 1st line of my answer.

Comment: The braches are actually deleted and `git branch -a` doesn't show anything. The problem is only in checkout autocomplete.

Comment: Yes, because it also exists in the remote repository.

Comment: I got it, I just had to launch `git remote prune origin` to update local repo. Anyway, thanks for the answers!

Answer (score 17):

**TL;DR** - the real answer:

```
$ git remote prune origin
```

**Slightly more details:**

`git branch -d foo-branch` will fail to delete if foo-branch is not merged into your current branch.

It's also a good idea to clean up old branches on a remote if they've already been merged. You can do this from the commandline by `git push origin :foo-branch`.

However, the old "phantom" branch foo-branch will linger for autocompleting git checkout. Apparently git is caching the branches available on the remote. By calling:

```
$ git remote prune origin
```

You can clear the local cache of what branches are available on the git remote.

I can reproduce the OP's issue for git 2.2.1 (and probably earlier versions) on OSX.

Answer (score 0):

You've probably tried to delete an `unmerged` branch, so `git branch -d branchname` has not deleted it.
You can check if the branch still exists with:

```
git branch -a
```

If you're **really sure** to delete the ~branch`even if is not`merged` you can *force* the deletion with:

```
git branch -D branchname
```

Comment: `git branch -a` shows only remote branches. Local branches that was deleted I can see only in checkout autocomplete.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem and the previous solutions didn't work for me. It turned out that I had a tag in the repo with the same name as the old deleted branch. You can delete the tag with:

`git tag -d [tagname]`

To delete it remotely:

`git push origin :refs/tags/[tagname]`

Thanks to https://nathanhoad.net/how-to-delete-a-remote-git-tag

Answer (score 0):

Note that pushing the branch deletion (`git push origin :branchname`) is easier in Git 2.13 (Q2 2017), since the completion script learned to complete "`git push --delete b<TAB>`" (to complete branch name to be deleted).

See [commit 723c1d5](https://github.com/git/git/commit/723c1d526faaee6fac9b804f4b97b148f450eb5d) (22 Apr 2017) by [Ævar Arnfjörð Bjarmason (`avar`)](https://github.com/avar).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit f70b541](https://github.com/git/git/commit/f70b54118897ffaa768ac48c9dabec36b293d09a), 26 Apr 2017)</sup>

Answer (score -1):

I realize this is really, really old, but I just ran into this issue, and in my case, I had pruned the branches in `origin`, but not the ones in `origin-http`.

I don't normally use http for cloning, so this is not typically an issue, but...welp.

Once I did `git remote prune origin-http`, it fixed the problem for me.