# clean git checkout autocompeletion

Tags: git, git-checkout, tab-completion

I'm using git with zsh

when I type in 'gco' and press the 'tab' key, it will be like the following

[image]

Those are not deleted or merged branches, but I don't want them.

Especially something like

`7038cc34  -- [HEAD]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure to use the latest Git 2.13, which improved on Git completion:

- for [deleted branch](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43726283/6309)
- for [remote branch](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43747486/6309)

In your case, check the `git branch -avv` output to see if those "branches" are listed at all. If not, it could be a new bug to report to the mailing list.